# proc_open() function returns 'PHP' is not recognized

Tags: php, multiprocessing, environment-variables, wamp, proc-open

I am using **Wamp** I want to get output from the file opened with proc_open()

```
$cwd=null;
$description = array(
    0 => array("pipe", "r"),
    1 => array("pipe", "w"),
    2 => array("file", "error-output.txt", "a") );

$process = proc_open("php child.php", $description, $pipes, $cwd);
    fclose($pipes[0]);
    echo stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
    fclose($pipes[1]);
    $return_value = proc_close($process);
    echo "command returned $return_value\n";
```

but it returns 'PHP' is not recognized as an internal or external command in error-output.txt
[image]

I have already included the path in environment variables and I can execute the command in **CMD**
or **VsCode** terminal

[image]

I have added the path in system variables
[System Variable picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/muHds.png)

But running the command **print_r(getenv('PATH'))** in the **child.php** printed the following

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;
C:\WINDOWS\system32;
C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;
C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn\;
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn\;
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn\;
C:\Program Files\Azure Data Studio\bin;
E:\Softwares\NodeJs\;
C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
```

So I don't know why the PHP path is not listed here
and I also don't know how to give path explicitly in the argument of
proc_open() as it accept an array for $env as official documentation says

```
$env = array('some_option' => 'aeiou');
```

Comment: What if you try `php.exe` instead?

Comment: the file name that I want to execute is **child.php**

Comment: And what does that have to do with replacing the _command_?

Comment: First I would try the full path.

Comment: sorry I thought you want me to change  like proc_open("php php.exe")

Comment: "I have already included the path in environment variables" - did you do this system-wide or for a single user. When you are testing from VS code you are running PHP under your account so it is getting your environment variables. You could try adding `var_dump(getenv('PATH'));` in your child to investigate, or you could use the full path, or you could explicitly pass a path in the `env_vars` param to `proc_open`

Comment: tried with "php.exe child.php" result is same

Comment: tried with the full path of the file but it didn't work

Comment: What's in your error log?

Comment: Picture of error log is displayed above. It says php is not recognised

Comment: "*tried with the full path*" - how, what path? Edit your question, show us.  "*it didn't work*" - what does this mean? What happened, exactly?  Edit your question, show us.  You need to specify the path to the php CLI executable.

Comment: I have used the full path for the file but don't know how to add PHP path in $env variable as it accepts an array. I have updated the question

Comment: Have you tried simply using the full path to PHP?  `$process = proc_open("C:\some\path\to\php.exe C:\path\to\child.php", $description, $pipes, $cwd);`?

Comment: @Don'tPanic that works thanks for your help. But can you tell me the way that I don't have to include the full path or at least I can put it in $ev variable